# File size in hive with different file formats

Tags: hive, orc

I have a small file (2MB). I created a external hive table over this file (stored as textfile). I created another table (stored as ORC) and copied the data from the previous table. When I checked the size of data in ORC table, it was more than 2MB.
ORC is a compressed file format, so shouldn't the data size be less?

Comment: Can anyone answer this question

Answer (score 1):

As of Hive 0.14, users can request an efficient merge of small ORC files together by issuing a CONCATENATE command on their table or partition. The files will be merged at the stripe level without reserialization.

ALTER TABLE istari [PARTITION partition_spec] CONCATENATE;

Answer (score 0):

It's because your source file is too small. ORC has complex structure with internal indexes, headers, footers, postscript, compressing codecs also add some structures, etc, etc. 
See this for details: [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileFormat](http://ORC%20file%20format)
All these supporting structures consume more space than the data. For such small file you really do not need to store min/max values for columns, do not need blum filters, etc since your file may fit in memory. The best storage for this case is text file uncompressed. You can also try just to gzip your source file and check it's size. Too small gzipped file may be bigger than uncompressed. The bigger the file the more benefit from compressing and using orc will be.